# Replacing zero elements with small random number in data table using R

Tags: r, replace, data.table, zero

I have the following data table. I need to replace the zero values in CPP column by small random number using R. This may be a simple task but I could not figure this out.

I tried this but giving me an error:

```
cty_d <- Table1[,sum(CPP==0)]
Table1[Table1 ==0] <- runif(cty_d,min=0.0001,max=0.001)
```

Any help is appreciated.

```
Table1:

    cty   year   CPP
    25    1998   0.0
    25    1999   100.2
    25    2000   25.2
    25    2001   535.0
    25    2002   0.0
    25    2003   0.0
    25    2004   75.2

Output:

    cty   year   CPP
    25    1998   0.0015
    25    1999   100.2
    25    2000   25.2
    25    2001   535.0
    25    2002   0.00014
    25    2003   0.0021
    25    2004   75.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Table1)[CPP == 0, CPP := runif(.N, min=0.0001, max=0.001)]
```

Takes Table1, subset to `CPP == 0`, then update CPP for that subset (`:=` updates by reference). `.N` is `data.table` syntax for # of observations. So 3 in your example table, since the subset of `CPP == 0` has 3 rows.

Comment: That's fair, although it seems like `Table1` is already a `data.table` judging from OP's code: `cty_d <- Table1[,sum(CPP==0)]` and `Table1[Table1 ==0]`

Comment: Thanks. I have the table as a data table format. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Using a workflow similar to the one in your post:

```
Table1$CPP[Table1$CPP==0] <- runif(sum(Table1$CPP==0),min=0.0001,max=0.001)
```

You just needed to overwrite the single column instead of the entire data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the RAND command with an update?

```
Update MyTable set CPP=(RAND() / 100) where CPP=0
```